# How to find a feature on map by its field data

Tags: qgis-plugins

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 & got much help to find a Featuer using 'Quick Finder' plugin.
Is it possible to locate a Feature (using a similar plugin like'Quick Finder'), on map using its attribute data (Not from Attribute Data Table wizard).

Sandipan Saha.

Comment: How and why does it need to be different than using the attribute table search function?